# Filtering data from multiple tables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am doing an iPad application. MY UIView will be as follows. there will be 2 UITabelview,
UITabelview and UIButton were tables are connected to the SQLite. the tough task is i want to select a row in each table and provide the related data in UITextview by using a UIButton (which is a search button).

Can any one suggest me to start a code or provide me any example.

Comment: please make it clear.. didn't get you want?

Comment: Hi..ok there are 2 UITableview  ex: one table which displays name and one Age, this tables are connected to SQLite for data. and one UIBUTTON which is Search Button, one UITextview. all this four objects are in one UIView(in one Page). my task is: for example if i select some X in name table and 23 in age table and press  UIButton(Search button). the data should display in UITextview related to that name and age from SQLite.

Comment: ok then why you are using two table views use one UIPickerView with two component after selecting the value you should pass this value to SQL query.

Comment: do u have any example of code to filter the data from two UIPickerView and display it in UITextView?????

Comment: it's a one Pickerview with two component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for UIPickerView with two component refer following link http://www.iphonetut.com/iphone_apps_-_interface_builder/86/uipickerview_with_two_component_example

this is the perfect answer for your query you need to just add your SQL functionality in button press event

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"I am feeling %@ for the activity %@",
                    [names objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]],
                    [age objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];

    NSLog(@"%@,%@",[nameArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]],[ageArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]);

    sqlite3 *database;
    NSMutableArray *Favorite=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { 
        NSLog(@"Open");
        NSString *sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM thirdTable WHERE name='%@' AND age='%@'", [nameArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], [ageArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
        NSLog(@"sqlTm p %@", sqlTmp);
        const char *sqlStmt=[sqlTmp UTF8String]; 
        sqlite3_stmt *cmp_sqlStmt; 
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStmt, -1, &cmp_sqlStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
             NSLog(@"prepare stmt ");
             while(sqlite3_step(cmp_sqlStmt)==SQLITE_ROW) { 

             NSString *a1=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(cmp_sqlStmt, 0)];
             NSMutableDictionary *Question=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           a1,@"detail",nil];
             [Favorite addObject:Question];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(cmp_sqlStmt);

sqlite3_close(database);

    if(Favourite.count >0){
      textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Favorite objectAtImadex:0]];
    }
[Favorite release];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks....I need a code for filtering the data and displaying it in UITextView, which is complicated for me and were i stuck...!!

Comment: have you getting your data from sqlite ? how many tables in your sqlite database?

Comment: 3 tabels, yes i am getting from sqlite

Comment: you need to show name + age in your textview like makumar 23?

Comment: no, there is a text in 3 tabel related to name and age. if i select name and age it should display the text in 3rd column related to that name and age.Ex: if i select cocoa matter in name and select age 23.. it will display the details about you in UITextview which is already in SQLite.

Comment: first thing u get both value from pickerview and pass it both value to sqlite select data query. B4 check the data is available or not. if the data is available then display the related data about details to uitextview. if not show alertview.

Comment: check the updated. it's just example to solve your problem it's not exactly what you want.